# Spring data source configuration issue :Logon Denied

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the below properties file in application.properties

```
# Database settings
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbbdev:1500:SIDNAME
spring.datasource.username=user$name
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=off
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My main class is below : -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
        System.out.println( "Hello World!  -- "  );
    }
```

I am getting the below error :-

> 2019-06-27 16:34:39.804  WARN 14556 --- [           main]
>   o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc
>   url from datasource
>
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
>   get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
>   obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException:
>   ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> aused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
>   denied
>
> at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319)
>   ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]    ... 65 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid
>   username/password; logon denied

I have checked my user name and password is correct .Following dependecy exis 
 exists in parent pom

How to resolve the issue.

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <ojdc.version>12.1.0.2.0</ojdc.version>


    </properties>
```

Comment: yes user$name is my username value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace that you have attached, shows that :

```
 [ main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

and the first part says that spring fails to determine the jdbc url from datasource. So, your jdbc url that you have provided in your `application.properties` is either wrong or it is not getting connected from your server.

Try providing the datasource url like :

```
# Database settings
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbbdev:1500/SIDNAME
```

if `SIDNAME` is your service name.

Comment: Getting the error : -
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385) ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.2.0]

Comment: In your property spring.datasource.password==password you have == instead of one.try removing it

Comment: damn it .that fixed it.Thanks a lot.I spent nearly 6 hours in this

Comment: @OracleMonkey Yup  we often miss the smaller things. :)